# How to check if user is authenticated in AngularJS router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, express

I have an application set up with the Mean.js yeoman generator. It uses PassportJS to setup local-authentication. This all works great and I understand how to check if a user is logged in from the ExpressJS routes file. 
The problem is that most of my page routing is done in the angular routes. I know how to check authentication in the controller with the the following code.

```
// Projects controller
angular.module('projects').controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Projects',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Projects) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;
```

But how do I check authentication in the routes. For example in this routes files how would I only allow authenticated users to access the tools html file and redirect users that arent logged in back to the home page:

```
'use strict';

//Setting up route
angular.module('analysis').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // Projects state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('imageAnalysis', {
            url: '/analysis',
            templateUrl: 'modules/analysis/views/tools.client.view.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

I know there are similar posts out there but I had trouble understanding many of them. Thanks, I really appreciate any help. I am new to the stackoverflow community and still learning community standards.

Comment: you could use `resolve` in your state https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: Couldn't you use a different controller for different routes + ui-router? Perhaps you could link to some of the 'similar posts out there' that you had trouble understanding? That would be helpful, as it gives potential answerers a better idea what you're trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, there are two approaches:

- Use your view routing layer (e.g. UI Router) to catch “unauthenticated” state
- Use HTTP interceptors to look for requests that have a `401 Unauthorized` status, indicating that the user must login (or that their current session has expired)

In practice you’ll probably use a combination of both.

Speaking to the UI Router, there a two of doing this: resolves or events.

**Resolves**: The UI Router provides a nice feature called resolves, which allows you to provide a promise that must be resolved before the view is rendered.  You could create a promise which resolves your user state.

**Events**: The UI Router provides a `$stateChangeStart` event, you can observe this event and prevent it if the user is not logged in.  You would then send the user to login page.  This is a bit more stateful (you have to remember where the user wanted to go in the first place, so that you can redirect after login).

I chose the event approach for my work on the [Stormpath Angular SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs) because it gives me the flexibility to define authorization on top of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for HTTP [Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Check auth on the requests.

From [OneHungryMind](http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/):

> HTTP interceptors are a great way to define behavior in a single place
>   for how a request or response is handled for ALL calls using the $http
>   service. This is a game changer when you want to set an auth token on
>   all outgoing calls or respond to a particular HTTP status error at the
>   system level. You can pair interceptors with the incredibly useful
>   Angular Storage module to cache an authenticated user and retrieve it
>   the next run time.

There are some good [tutorials(1)](https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/) [out there(2)](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Since I can already access the authentication object in my controller, isn't there some way to put that authentication object in the scope so I can access it somehow in my router file?